# Postgres deadlock happened with multi-column unique constraint when upsert single record

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, unique-constraint, upsert, postgres-14

#### Abstract

1. What is '**speculative token**'?
2. Why **deadlock** is happened? I've tried `upsert` just **single row** with `insert.. with on conflict.. do update` syntax.
3. There was `UNIQUE INDEX index_foo_date ON table_a USING btree (foo_id, date)`. This error is disappeared after I got rid of `UNIQUE constraint of (foo_id, date)`. But I'd like to know exact reason.

#### Errors

I've got so many these errors at the same time. In my code, there is just upsert single column syntax.

```sql
DataAccessException

SQL [insert into "public"."table_a" ("id", "foo_id", "date", "counter")
  values ('1:2023-12-17', '5', cast('2023-12-17' as date), 1)
  on conflict ("id") do update set "counter" = ("public"."table_a"."counter" + 1)];
  ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 3208 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2964346221; blocked by process 2511.
          Process 2511 waits for ShareLock on speculative token 3 of transaction 2964346220;
          blocked by process 3208.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
  Where: while inserting index tuple (12512,98) in relation "index_foo_date"
```

```sql
SQL [insert into "public"."table_a" ("id", "foo_id", "date", "counter")
  values ('1:2023-12-17', '5', cast('2023-12-17' as date), 1)
  on conflict ("id") do update set "counter" = ("public"."table_a"."counter" + 1)];
  ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_foo_date"
  Detail: Key (foo_id, date)=(5, 2023-12-17) already exists.
```

```sql
SQL [insert into "public"."table_a" ("id", "foo_id", "date", "counter")
  values ('1:2023-12-17', '5', cast('2023-12-17' as date), 1)
  on conflict ("id") do update set "counter" = ("public"."table_a"."counter" + 1)];
  ERROR: deadlock detected
  Detail: Process 3034 waits for ShareLock on speculative token 7 of transaction 2964312410; blocked by process 2994.
          Process 2994 waits for ShareLock on transaction 2964320791;
          blocked by process 3034.
  Hint: See server log for query details.
```

#### More Info

1. Table

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  id CHARACTER VARYING PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  foo_id CHARACTER VARYING REFERENCES foo(id) NOT NULL,
  date DATE NOT NULL,
  counter INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_foo_date ON table_a USING btree (foo_id, date);
```

2. `id` has `foo_id:date` form such as `'5:2023-12-17'`

#### My thought

1. As a result of my local testing,

   - when a psql **sessionA** had `ExclusiveLock`, other sessions(**sessionB**, **sessionC**) are blocked and waiting to get `ShareLock`.
   - When **sessionA** got `commit;` **sessionB** got `ExclusiveLock`.
   - And then **sessionC** worked same. so I don't know why...
2. I've got some keywords.

   - speculative token / speculative insertion lock / sepculative-execution
   - unique composite index
3. I feel like it's related to unique constraint about composite fields `foo_id` and `date`. But I can't figure out exact reason.

Comment: If you are using `ON CONFLICT (id)`, you can still get a unique constraint violation on a different constraint. About the deadlocks, please add the details from the log to the question.

Comment: there are no more logs. It's all. Even I've used debug mode

Comment: Oh yes, there are. On the database server.